# XSLT check if one of sibling elements contain certain parameter

Tags: xml, xslt, properties, filter

I have XML which lists my menu items. Problem is, it lists all items regardless of their language and I need to filter out all items that don't belong to current language which is stored in `$language` variable.

This is my XSLT which is supposed to filter out menu items that don't belong to current language (it's also supposed to filter hidden items):

`<xsl:apply-templates select="page[not(types/type = 'hidden' or types/type != $language)]"/>`

Currently, only about element get's through and that is probably because my `Home` item also has `index` besides `en`.

So, how can I filter out element if it doesn't contain correct `type` with current language in it, while ignoring other properties?

This is my XML:

```
<navigation>
    <page handle="en" id="1">
        <name>Home</name>
        <types>
            <type>en</type>
            <type>index</type>
        </types>
    </page>
    <page handle="he" id="2">
        <name>Home HE</name>
        <types>
            <type>he</type>
        </types>
    </page>
    <page handle="about" id="3">
        <name>About</name>
        <types>
            <type>en</type>
        </types>
    </page>
</navigation>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with the not() function, which doesn't work in the way that you're trying to use it. not() takes a number, string, or node set, applies the boolean() function, then returns the inverse. not() will apparently not invert a boolean expression. See http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp#boolean

You can achieve what you want by distributing the inverse operator into the operands and using "and":

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="page[types/type != 'hidden' and types/type = $language]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For comparison on element values, use text()

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="page[not(types/type/text() = 'hidden' or types/type/text() != $language)]"/>
```

Comment: This produces the same incorrect result as OP's XPATH query in .NET 4.5.